# Push file create by Django than need to be ignore by git

Tags: django, git, gitlab, gitignore

I have make a first push to Gitlab with git, but the.gitignore wasn't completely configure.
I configure the .gitignore like this now :

```
# Environments
env/
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
poc_project/poc_project/__pycache__
poc_project/pollution/__pycache__
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class
# Django stuff:
*.log
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal
```

The `env`/ and `poc_project/poc_project/__pycache__` aren't push but the `db.sqlite3` and `poc_project/pollution/__pycache__` are already on the distant repository (Gitlab).
I use this https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore for configure my .gitignore because I use django. My teammate will soon start working on the project.

It's a problem to have *pycache* file and *db.sqlite3* for team work on distant repository with Django?
If yes how can I delete these files correctly from gitlab repository ?

Comment: the same issus with me but , you can use branch for everyone in your team in the last marge all

Comment: Just delete the files/directories, commit the deletion and push again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they do not contain any sensitive information: just delete the files and commit the deletion. If they do contain sensitive information they would still be present in the history, even after you delete the files. That requires some additional work, see: [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)